# Python TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, jupyter-notebook, entropy

I am trying to take the entropy of my k-means result dataframe and I am getting the error back: TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable
I dont understand why.

```
from collections import Counter 
def calcEntropy(x):
    p, lens = Counter(x), np.float(len(x))
    return -np.sum(count/lens*np.log2(count/lens) for count in p.values())
k_means_sp['entropy']=[calcEntropy(x) for x in k_means_sp['cluster']]
```

and then I get the error message:

```
<ipython-input-26-d375ecf00330> in <module>()
----> 1 k_means_sp['entropy']=[calcEntropy(x) for x in k_means_sp['cluster']]

<ipython-input-26-d375ecf00330> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 k_means_sp['entropy']=[calcEntropy(x) for x in k_means_sp['cluster']]

<ipython-input-23-f5508ea8782c> in calcEntropy(x)
      1 from collections import Counter
      2 def calcEntropy(x):
----> 3     p, lens = Counter(x), np.float(len(x))
      4     return -np.sum(count/lens*np.log2(count/lens) for count in p.values())

/Users/mpiercy/anaconda/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py in __init__(*args, **kwds)
    535             raise TypeError('expected at most 1 arguments, got %d' % len(args))
    536         super(Counter, self).__init__()
--> 537         self.update(*args, **kwds)
    538 
    539     def __missing__(self, key):

/Users/mpiercy/anaconda/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py in update(*args, **kwds)
    622                     super(Counter, self).update(iterable) # fast path when counter is empty
    623             else:
--> 624                 _count_elements(self, iterable)
    625         if kwds:
    626             self.update(kwds)

TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable

k_means_sp.head()

      credit    debit   cluster
0   9.207673    8.198884    1
1   4.248495    8.202181    0
2   8.149668    7.735145    2
3   5.138677    7.859741    0
4   8.058163    7.918614    2
```

Comment: assuming `k_means_sp` is holding `numpy.int32`, then you're passing a `numpy.int32` to `Counter`.  `Counter` should be taking an `iterable`.

Comment: what does that mean that i should make the cluster column be cluster = [0,1,2] and y = iter(cluster) or am i doing this completely wrong? thanks!

Comment: @bananablue1 It means that you cannot pass an integer to `calcEntropy` as it is currently written. The right thing to do depends on your aim. If you want `calcEntropy` to work with integers (does that make any sense?) then you should fix it, if you want to pass something else to `calcEntropy` then pass something else, etc.

Comment: @Goyo i am new to this i want it to work on my cluster column, how do i do this? thanks!

Comment: @bananablue1 "work on my cluster column" does not clarify much. What do you want to do with your cluster column?

Comment: I want to use entropy as an external validation for my k means clusters

Comment: The entropy of what?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to calculate the entropy of each cluster right? So shouldn't you pass in a cluster to calcEntropy()?

Comment: @RobbieJones there is not a lot of documentation and im really struggling with this, yes, i want to calculate the entropy of each cluster I am stuck though

Comment: You need to post more of your code then, it's hard to tell what `k_means_sp` is storing

Comment: @RobbieJones I just posted k_means_sp.head()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is a first attempt.  It looks like your dataframe stores the cluster index in the `'cluster'` column.  So what you need to do is get each cluster based on the index, and then pass that cluster to your `calcEntropy` function, something like

```
for i in xrange(len(k_means_sp['cluster'].unique())) # loop thru cluster indices:
    cluster = k_means_sp.ix[k_means_sp['cluster'] == i][['credit', 'debit']]
    entropy = calcEntropy(cluster)
```

The second line filters out the rows to only the ones that have the same cluster index.  Does this help?